# How to insert values in a table which has user defined types?

Tags: cassandra, cql, user-defined-types, scylla

I am working with Scylla (Cassandra) db and trying to create tables which is dealing with `User-Defined Types` as shown below:

```
CREATE TYPE process (
    id int,
    discount float
);

CREATE TYPE service (
    id int,
    url text
);

CREATE TABLE data (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    fname text,
    lname text,
    service set<frozen<service>>,
    monthly_process frozen<process>
);
```

My confusion is how can I insert data in my `data` table. Problem is I am confuse how `process` and `service` type works here and how can I insert values in them?

I tried with below example but it gave me an error:

```
insert into test (id, fname, lname, service, monthly_process ) 
values (1, 'abc', 'world', {'service': [{'id':1, 'url': 'some_url1'},
{'id':2, 'url': 'some_url2'}]}, {'id':1, 'discount': 10.0});
```

**Error I got:**

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
message="Invalid map literal for service of type set<frozen<service>>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version of your query;

```
insert into data (id, fname, lname, service, monthly_process)
values (2, 'abc', 'world', {{id: 1, url: 'some'}, {id : 2, url:'another'}}, {id:1, discount: 10.0});
```

- `service set<frozen<service>>` format would be `{{id:1, url:'a'}, {id:2, url:'b'}}`
- `monthly_process frozen<process>` format is `{id:1, discount: 10.0}`